# Can I control column breaks in an HTML list that uses multicolumn CSS?

Tags: css, html-lists, css-multicolumn-layout

What I have is one HTML semantic list spanning three columns via CSS:

```
ul {column-count: 3;}
```

What I want to do is to control where the list items (the `<li>` elements) break across the columns. It happens to be an alphabetized list, so instead of, say, nine items appearing three each per column, like this:

```
apple      beet          broccoli 
apricot    blackberry    carrot 
bean       blueberry     cherry
```

I want them to appear like this:

```
apple      bean          carrot 
apricot    beet          cherry
           blackberry     
           blueberry 
           broccoli
```

I have tried this:

> **Breaks before and after boxes**—The break-before and break-after properties are used to control breaks before and after elements.... In
> this next example, we are forcing a column break before an h2
> element.
>   <sub>Source: [MDN Web Docs—Handling content breaks in
> multicol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Handling_content_breaks_in_multicol)</sub>

However, it's not working at the example there (`h2 {break-before: column;}`) as viewed in Firefox (the h2 remains at the bottom of column 1). Nor is it working on my list (e.g. `li.break-here {break-before: column;}`)

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page-break-after: always;` and/or `page-break-before: always;` as `style` attributes or in classes which you apply to the according `li` elements. ("page-..." will also apply to the columns in this situation)

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to work for me either. I will try some more methodological experiments to see where it's going wrong.